# Use $$...$$ or \[...\] to enter math mode in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode

I read on some sites that [ ... ] (with backslashes before the brackets) should be used, rather that `$$...$$`

what is the difference between both? If you compare the output, the result is the same.

Comment: This is an 'FAQ' and indeed `$$` is _not_ LaTeX syntax.

Comment: Sorry about the duplicate... Didn't find the post while searching myself.